# $http.delete not sending authorization header angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that deletes data on a resource, i have the following code however the Authorization header is not getting passed.

```
 var config = {
     headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + apiToken
     }
 };

 promise = $http.delete(urlRoute+'/subscriptions/'+subscriptionId, config)
    .success(function(response){
        return response.data;
    })
    .error(function(response){
        console.log('error while deleting');
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The request does not go thru since the Auth header is never passed

Comment: Can you confirm that the header isn't present by looking at the data in your browser's *Network* developer console?

Comment: yes confirming that i dont see the header

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. If i change the method to 'get' for example, then it will send the header authorization item.

Comment: Has this been resolved?